# How can I import a pybind11-generated module in docker

Tags: docker, pybind11

For a normal python module, I can just add

```
COPY /path/to/module /path/to/module
```

in my Dockerfile and my python script in docker can import the module normally. However, if the module is generated by pybind11 following this simple tutorial https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html, even if I have

```
COPY /path/to/example.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /path/to/example.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I still could not import the module from my python script in docker. I am wondering how I can resolve that?
The most brute force way is to have a lot of RUN statements in Dockerfile to rebuild my c++ library and re-run the binding step, but I do not want to re-run these steps after I have already done so on the host machine. So I am curious if there is a cleaner solution?